# addEventListener("load") not working properly in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
<script id="js-cookie"></script>
<script id="vk-info"></script>
<script>
    document.querySelector("#jquery").addEventListener("load", onLoadJQuery);
    function onLoadJQuery() {
        document.querySelector("#js-cookie").setAttribute("src", "/js.cookie.js");
        document.querySelector("#js-cookie").addEventListener("load", onLoadJSCookie);
    }
    function onLoadJSCookie() {
        document.querySelector("#vk-info").setAttribute("src", "/vk-info.js");
    }
```

I've used this kind of check all the time, and it worked in Firefox.

Basically jQuery is loaded in my master template, then in its child template I also load some scripts, but consequentially. So at first it's supposed to check if jQuery is loaded, then load JS-Cookie, and when it's loaded, then load my custom script. But on Chrome it doesn't work for some reason.

I can see that jquery is loaded in DOM and it has id `#jquery`. But even when it's loaded, my other scripts don't load. They don't get any src attribute and stay empty. I triple checked their sources, and everything is correct. Especially because they load fine without EventListener.

Any help is appreciated, maybe I'm missing something. But in Firefox everything DOES work.

Comment: where do you define an element with the `id` of jquery?

Comment: @DerekPollard in another template that is the parent template of the one where I define other scripts. I stated it in my question. The element with the id `jquery` is in DOM, I can see it there. It's the same page, just two different Twig files. No difference at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we can't see how you are loading the jQuery script tag, it's hard to tell for sure, but it's likely that the problem is that the `load` event has already fired before the handler is registered.

Different browsers have [different strategies to load as fast as possible](https://bitsofco.de/async-vs-defer/), so exact load sequences may differ between them.  If you set a script tag's `src` before its `load` handler, you have no guarantee that the handler will run, even if the tag loads successfully.  It may seem to work reliably in some browsers, but that could easily change in new versions as new loading strategies are adopted.

If you cannot ensure that the script's `load` handler is set before `src`, you might be able to detect whether the load has already happened by checking for side effects of running the jQuery script, like maybe:

```
    if (window.jQuery) {
        onLoadJQuery();
    } else {
        document.querySelector("#jquery").addEventListener("load", onLoadJQuery);
    }
```

Comment: I just moved those scripts higher in the DOM, and it magically worked, I don't know for what reason. Case closed. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Actually, it still helped me in a different situation.